# Moving files between user entered directories

Tags: c

I'm attempting to move the dummy.txt from one user entered directory, however it fails to do so. Both directories exist and dummy.txt exists, however it still fails no matter what I do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
  int ret, ttime, oldfile, newfile, placeholder1, placeholder2;
  int lloop = 0;
  printf("Enter directory of dummy.txt: ");
  scanf("%d", &oldfile);
  printf("Enter new directory: ");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%d", &newfile);
  printf("Starting");

  time_t begin = time(NULL);

  while (lloop != 2) {
    char oldname[] = "%d", oldfile;
    char newname[] = "%d", newfile;
    ret = rename(oldname, newname);

    if (ret == 0) {
      printf("\nFile moved successfully\n");
    } else {
      printf("\nError: unable to move file\n");
    }
    lloop = lloop + 1;
    placeholder1 = oldfile;
    placeholder2 = newfile;
    newfile = placeholder1;
    oldfile = placeholder2;

  }

  time_t end = time(NULL);
  ttime = end - begin;
  printf("Transfer took %d seconds\n", ttime);

  return (0);
}
```

Comment: What is `char oldname[] = "%d", oldfile;` supposed to do?

Comment: If you do not compiler warnings in this code, you should turn up the diagnostics.  If you do get warnings, you should heed them.

Comment: `-Wall` or equivalent would help a *lot* here. You're using `int` in places it just does not belong.

Comment: `rename` sets `errno` which tells you why it failed.  You might find it easy to diagnose if you replace `printf("\nError: unable to move file\n");` with something like `perror(oldname)` or `fprintf(stderr, "unable to rename %s to %s: %s\n", oldname, newname, strerror(errno));`

Comment: @tadman I would expected warnings as well, but it seems gcc doesn't warn about this at all. It is legit c syntax, though it is very confusing. It defines a new variable of type `char*` which shadows the previous  definition.

Comment: @Davidvanrijn In its current very confused form it doesn't have any errors, but all it does is rename a file named`%d` to `%d` over and over. As soon as that's corrected, the type errors will surface if warnings are on.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a printf on oldname and newname, you will see that they are literally `"%d"` which makes sense, because that is what you put in them.

Maybe you forgot to use `sprintf`?

---

In C strings are not smart what you see is what you get (except for `\n` etc. escapes).
So there is no implicit string formatting. That always has to be done in a function. In this case you probably meant to do something like this:

```
char oldname[12];
char newname[12];
sprintf(oldname, "%d", oldfile);
sprintf(newname, "%d", newfile);
printf("old: %s\nnew: %s\n", oldname, newname);
```

Comment: I think the confusion maybe comes from using a higher level language, where the syntax for string substitution is similar to what OP wrote, rather than with forgetting to use `sprintf`. As such, I think a couple lines of code to show how to use `sprintf` would be good to show in this answer.

Comment: good pont, just edited. You are right, acutally. It does really look like the old python string format operator

Comment: The directories are now being detected and changed properly, however it fails to move the file.                                                                                                           `Enter directory of dummy.txt: C:\x
Enter new directory: C:\y
Starting

old: 1981443885
new: 6356712

Error: unable to move file

old: 6356712
new: 1981443885

Error: unable to move file

Transfer took 0 seconds`

Comment: There was a useful comment on your original question, which told you how to print the error of `rename()` I would start by doing that first, so you know what's going on

Comment: I've done that and it's saying that the directories are invalid, however they aren't, cd works perfectly fine with them and they're copied directly from file explorer, is there some sort of special formatting?